# Objective-C RegexKitLite match one string or another

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm trying to use regexkitlite for string matching in objective-c and I'm having some problems with it.  What I'm trying to do is search a large string for substrings matching:

- "http://[something].jpg"
- "http://[something].png"

Basically, I want to find all links to images from the original string.  What I have currently is:

```
NSString *regexString = @"http://[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-/]+\.jpg";
```

Now this is working for .jpg images, but of course it doesn't match .png images.  I would really like to use one regexString that would match either, but I can't figure out how.

Reading some regex tutorials for other languages, I think it is something along the lines of:

```
NSString *regexString = @"http://[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-/]+\.(?:jpg|png)";
```

But I can't quite get it right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The re is basically correct, what is questionable is if `RegexKitLite` supports the non-matching parenthesis (?:  Personally I have moved to the Apple supplied: `NSRegularExpression`, iOS 4.0+.

Comment: The regex is correct. What makes you think it isn't? What are your results?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a non-capturing group around the file extensions.  It's good practice to use them, but it could be causing an error here. (Does the library support it?)

Also, I simplified your regex slightly by using a predefined character class.

```
NSString *regexString = @"http://[\w.%+-/]+\.(jpg|png)";
```

You can see this in action [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=http%3A%2F%2F%5B%5Cw.%25%2B-%2F%5D%2B%5C.%28jpg%7Cpng%29&input=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fsomething.jpg%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fsomething-Else.png%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain2.com%2FshouldntMatch.php%0A).

You can also add any file extensions that you want. Ex: `(jpg|png|gif|...)`.

**Updated:** Apple now includes regular expression support with [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which is available in OS X v10.7 and later.